# SQL query to create separate dataframes for each distinct combination of values of 4 database columns?

Tags: python, sql, oracle

How can I create multiple dataframes from all possible combinations of 4 columns in  a Oracle database table in Python?

How can I write such a SQL query wherein all records fetched will be loaded to my dataframe? I am using Oracle12c

Lets say my column names are 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D'. Their number of distinct values in my database table are 4, 3, 2, 6 respectively. Here total combinations possible are 4*3*2*6 = 144. So basically i need 144 dataframes.

Now I want to load all records fetched from one combination of these values (lets say A1-B1-C1-D1) in one dataframe, all records fetched from other combination of these values (A1-B1-C1-D2) in next dataframe and so on and so forth.

I am new to this whole thing so getting stuck here.

Comment: It looks like you're trying to generate rows by scrambling column values. Almost like treating each column as if it belongs to a different table and then running a cartesian product. Does that sound reasonable?

Comment: No all columns are in the same table. Thats why no concept of join applicable here.

Comment: Why do you want them in separate dataframes? That's a very odd choice. I would be willing to bet that you'd have a far easier time overall in whatever you're coding if you put everything into a single dataframe.

Comment: Can cross join be applied to columns in the same table?

Comment: Its like I want to perform some logic on each dataframe. Its like running the query in iterations:query produced one dataframe- some logic ran over that df-some df transform happened-transformed df stored back to database table

Comment: @Prachi Rather than having 144 dataframes and performing logic on each dataframe, you can just have one dataframe and apply logic to each combination of ABCD in the dataframe. This is easily accomplished with a popular dataframe package like pandas.

Comment: Can you please tell me how to do this?

Comment: @Prachi I have written up an answer that may get you started. It will at least give you an idea of how you could get one big dataframe stored locally on your computer using the pandas package. In regards to applying logic to each ABCD combo, much depends on the specifics of the logic you want to apply. But I am confident that anything you want to do could be handled well by the pandas package and one big dataframe. Pandas was created for tasks like these.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wouldn't your query just end up downloading the entire table as it is? If you find every distinct combination of columns A,B,C,D and then join your table onto those combinations, then you'll simply get back the original table.

Could you instead create a new column that concatenates the values of A,B,C,D?

```
select
  A || '-' || B || '-' || C || '-' || D as ABCD
, A
, B
, C
, D
from my_table
```

Output would be:

```
ABCD           A    B    C    D
A1-B1-C1-D1    A1   B1   C1   D1
A1-B1-C1-D2    A1   B1   C1   D2
```

Bring that into a dataframe like so:

```
import pandas as pd
query = """
        select
          A || '-' || B || '-' || C || '-' || D as ABCD
          , A
          , B
          , C
          , D
        from my_table
        """
df = pd.read_sql(sql = query, con = conn)
```

Now you have a dataframe with a new column ABCD that you can use to group on all your A,B,C,D scenarios. I would highly recommend against breaking these up into separate dataframes. Why would you want to do that, I wonder?

If you want to refer to a particular scenario, then just do this:

```
df[df['ABCD'] == 'A1-B1-C1-D1']
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to `SELECT` each set of values and `CROSS JOIN` them together.  E.g.,

```
SELECT     a, b, c, d
FROM       ( SELECT a FROM my_table ) xa
CROSS JOIN ( SELECT b FROM my_table ) xb
CROSS JOIN ( SELECT c FROM my_table ) xc
CROSS JOIN ( SELECT d FROM my_table ) xd
```

You may want to modify the subqueries to select `DISTINCT` values, possibly.

This will give you a result set with all possible combinations of values from the four columns.

> Now I want to load all records fetched from one combination of these values (lets say A1-B1-C1-D1) in one dataframe, all records fetched from other combination of these values (A1-B1-C1-D2) in next dataframe and so on and so forth.

I don't know what a "dataframe" is, so I can't help you with that part.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming Python's `pandas` library, consider loading *entire* query as is and then run `groupby` to build a list or dictionary of 144 data frames. This answers:

> How can I create multiple dataframes from all possible combinations of 4 columns...?

It is much better to store many similar structured objects in **one** container instead of 144 separate objects flooding your global environment. You lose no functionality of data frame if stored inside a list or dictionary.

```
sql_df = pd.read_sql("""SQL Query""", conn)

# DICTIONARY COMPREHENSION
df_dict = {i:g for i,g in sql_df.groupby(['A', 'B', 'C', 'D']) }

# REFERENCE INDIVIDUAL DFs WITH TUPLE KEYS
df_dict[(A1, B1, C1, D1)].head()

df_dict[(A1, B1, C1, D2)].describe()

df_dict[(A1, B1, C1, D3)].tail()
```

To avoid tuple keys, map values into a single string keys with underscore delimiter:

```
df_dict = {"_".join(map(str, i)):g for i,g in sql_df.groupby(['A', 'B', 'C', 'D']) }

# REFERENCE INDIVIDUAL DFs WITH TUPLE KEYS
df_dict['A1_B1_C1_D1'].head()

df_dict['A1_B1_C1_D2'].describe()

df_dict['A1_B1_C1_D3'].tail()
```